# Is it possible to initiate the User state migration in SCCM?

Tags: sccm

I am a developer who has only overall knowledge on SCCM 2012 and how the user state migration works. I have scenario where the target computer's information is not available while intend to take backup on old device (Laptop or Desktop). Is that possible to execute Task sequence associated with backup part of the user state migration with out the computer association in SCCM and specify the target computer details while just before the restore of the backup? Sometimes organizations place the order as a bulk for new devices and the associated to a certain employee as a last part of the overall workflow. If anyone has faced this kind of situation please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Create Computer Association is required when doing side-by-side deployments (Migrate from one computer to another). The association should be created before deploying the capturing User State task sequence.

In your case, I think you can do as followings:

1. Import the new computers' information from a CSV file (pre-populated with Computer name, MAC address or UUID of the new devices).
2. Create computer association between source computers and destination computers.
3. Deploy the capturing User state task sequence to capture user state from the old devices to the SMP.
4. When you receive the new devices, deploy the OSD task sequence to the new devices to build the OS and restore use state from SMP.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases a manual User state backup is just simpler.

To run a USMT backup/restore fast and simple consider running it with EhlerTecs GUI for USMT 10.
/Janine